# solve the equation $\left(z^{2}+1\right)^{n}-(z-1)^{2 n}=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Im trying to solve the eq $$(E)\quad \left(z^{2}+1\right)^{n}-(z-1)^{2 n}=0$$
My attemp :

By Newton i get

$$\left(z^{2}+1\right)^{n}-(z-1)^{2n}=0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) z^{2 k}-\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) z^{k}=0$$
which leaves us with : $$-\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
1
\end{array}\right) z-\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
3
\end{array}\right) z^{3}-\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
5
\end{array}\right) z^{5} \cdots-\left(\begin{array}{c}
2n \\
2n-1
\end{array}\right) z^{n}=0$$.I got stuck there.

Comment: Note that \binom{n}{k} is built-in to display $\binom{n}{k}$ and should be used rather than using array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $(z^2+1)^n -(z-1)^{2n}=0$ we have $(z^2+1)^n = ((z-1)^2)^n$, then $$\left(\frac{z^2+1}{(z-1)^2}\right)^n = 1$$

That means $\frac{z^2+1}{(z-1)^2} = \xi$, an $n$-th root of unity. Now just solve the quadratic. You'll get $2n-1$ solutions, $2$ for each $n$-th root of unity with the exception of $\xi = 1$ which gives only one solution.

Comment: (+1) I could have corrected my answer, but since yours appeared first…